# How can I sort a field in numerical order after FORMAT() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

After using `FORMAT()` to strip some unnecessary decimal places from my result, I'm unable to correctly order by that field, as that field is now a String rather than a number.

What is good practice to order results and then remove decimal places (or vice versa) so that they are ordered in correct numerical order?

---

**Results before FORMAT**

```
ORDER BY `Field` ASC

*---------*
| 1000.06 |
| 2000.17 |
| 3000.12 |
| 10000.4 |
| 20000.1 |
| 30000.2 |
*---------*
```

Results are sorted numerically but there are unneeded decimal places that need to be removed.

---

**Results after FORMAT()**

```
ORDER BY `Field` ASC   

*---------*
| 1,000   |
| 10,000  |
| 2,000   |
| 20,000  |
| 3,000   |
| 30,000  |
*---------*
```

Results have had decimal places removed but as `FORMAT()` has made the field a string then it is not sorting numerically as we require, but alphabetically.

---

**Required Results**

```
*---------*
| 1,000   |
| 2,000   |
| 3,000   |
| 10,000  |
| 20,000  | 
| 30,000  |
*---------*
```

The required result is for the results to be sorted numerically and have the decimal places removed.

Comment: I should say, I tried slapping a `CAST()` around it but it caused errors. (The previous line which was `FORMAT(... , 0) AS Field` became `CAST(FORMAT(... , 0 ) AS INTEGER) AS Field` but this caused errors.) As I wasn't sure if this was the ideal order to be doing this in (i.e. good practice) I thought I would ask.

Comment: Am I understanding correct if I say that: you have a number. You convert it to a string. You want to convert it back to a number and sort ?

Comment: I have numbers with messy decimal places I don't need (e.g. `1,000.00067`). I need to both *remove the decimal places* and sort it correctly by numerical order. I was advised to use `FORMAT()` to remove the decimal places however I am not sure if this is compatible with ordering in numerical order and if so what the best practice is to do so.

Comment: `1,000.00067` - is it a number or a string?

Comment: You could sort by the value `before` format.

Comment: `1000.0067` is a number. I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: If it is a number - just sort by it?

Comment: @zerkms Then when do I remove the decimal places I don't want to display?

Comment: @Eilidh: sorting has nothing to do with formatting/displaying.

Answer (score 4):

Just select the formatted value and order by the unformatted one.

```
SELECT FORMAT(value, 0) FROM t ORDER BY value ASC
```

Comment: My value is derived from other fields, so it's actually more like `((SUM(FieldOne)) / (SUM(CASE WHEN FieldTwo != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Field` - I'm not sure how to do it in this case when it's more complex? 

Sorry if that's a silly question. I'm very new to this.

Comment: it works for me, in my case

select ..., FORMAT(**sum(T.value)**,2) as 'Total',... from  table T 
...
where ... order by **sum(T.value)** ...

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT ROUND(value, 0) rounded_value FROM t ORDER BY rounded_value ASC
```

`ROUND()` will do the same thing as `FORMAT()` but returns a number rather than a char

Comment: Not true: FORMAT will preserve trailing zeroes, while ROUND will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need the `FORMAT` for is removing the decimal places, just get rid of it and use something like `CAST(... AS signed)` instead.